# MVC Routing to controller in another project 404 error

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc

I have created an "area" in another project.  This area is loaded dynamically when the application starts using reflection.  After loading the dll, I manually load the area from the loaded assembly by calling `RegisterArea`.  Also, the project cshtml files are moved from the loaded area's directory into the main web app's directory when the project builds.

In the `AreaRegistration` in the other project, I set the following route.

```
context.MapRoute(
   "Client_default",
   "PrintPage/{action}/{id}",
   new
   {
      controller = "PrintPage",
      action = "APrintPage",
      id = UrlParameter.Optional
   },
   new[] {
      "AppName.Client.WebApp.Controllers"
   }
);
```

The `PrintPageController` is in the `AppName.Client.WebApp.Controllers` namespace in the dynamically loaded dll.  When I try to navigate to the action using `~/PrintPage/APrintPage` I am getting a 404 error. I downloaded the [Route Debugger Package](https://www.nuget.org/packages/routedebugger/) in an attempt to see if the route just wasn't getting mapped properly.  However, the debugger is indicating that not only is the route mapped, but is matching the url provided.

[image: Output from route debugger showing the route is matching]

My controller method signatures:

```
[HttpGet]
public ActionResult ViolationResult()

[HttpGet]
public ActionResult ViolationWarning(int[] ids)
```

Now, I am not surprised that the second one might have issues getting routed properly, but I am lost on why the first action is not getting hit.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ended up figuring it out.  The default controller factory (`System.Web.Mvc.DefaultControllerFactory`) contained a controller type cache (`System.Web.Mvc.ControllerTypeCache`).  The type cache loads the controller types from an internal file *"MVC-ControllerTypeCache.xml"* embedded in the assembly when the project is built.  Since the assemblies containing the views that where loaded at runtime and not built with the project, the controller type cache did not contain a type for the controller even though the route matched.  No controller means 404 error.

For a fix, I simply created a class inheriting from `System.Web.Mvc.DefaultControllerFactory`, overrode the method `GetControllerType`, and used my own implementation of the controller type cache that grabs all the classes implementing `IController` from the loaded assemblies and then uses that cache to determine the controller type.

Note: Some of the code was copied from the `DefaultControllerFactory` due to certain members being declared internal.

```
public class ControllerFactory : DefaultControllerFactory
{
    private static volatile Dictionary<string, Lookup<string, Type>> _ctcache;
    private static readonly object Lock = new object();

    private static Dictionary<string, Lookup<string, Type>> ControllerTypeCache
    {
        get
        {
            if (_ctcache != null)
                return _ctcache;

            FillTypeCache();

            return _ctcache;
        }
    }

    protected override Type GetControllerType(RequestContext requestContext, string controllerName)
    {
        var routeData = requestContext.RouteData;

        //This comes from the DefaultControllerFactory.  I don't use attribute routing.
        if (routeData?.Values.ContainsKey("MS_DirectRouteMatches") ?? false)
            throw new NotImplementedException();

        object obj = null;
        if (!(routeData?.DataTokens.TryGetValue("Namespaces", out obj) ?? false))
            return null;

        var namespaces = (obj as IEnumerable<string>)?.Distinct(StringComparer.OrdinalIgnoreCase).ToArray();

        if ((namespaces == null) || !namespaces.Any())
            return null;

        return ControllerTypeCache[controllerName].SingleOrDefault(x => namespaces.Any(y => IsNamespaceMatch(y, x.Key)))?
            .SingleOrDefault();
    }

    private static void FillTypeCache()
    {
        lock (Lock)
        {
            if (_ctcache != null)
                return;

            var isController = new Func<Type, bool>(x => x.GetInterfaces().Any(y => y == typeof(IController)));

            var asm = System.Reflection.Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly();
            var defaultControllers = asm.GetTypes().Where(isController);

            //Loaded is a class containing items initialized at Application_Start
            //FromConfig is an IEnumerable<System.Reflection.Assembly>
            var loadedControllers = Loaded.FromConfig.SelectMany(x => x.GetTypes().Where(isController));

            _ctcache = defaultControllers.Union(loadedControllers)
                .GroupBy(x => x.Name)
                .ToDictionary(x => x.Key.Replace("Controller", ""), types => types.ToLookup(y => y.Namespace) as Lookup<string, Type>);
        }
    }

    //Lifted from the DefaultControllerFactory since it's an internal method.
    private static bool IsNamespaceMatch(string requestedNamespace, string targetNamespace)
    {
        if (requestedNamespace == null)
        {
            return false;
        }
        if (requestedNamespace.Length == 0)
        {
            return true;
        }
        if (!requestedNamespace.EndsWith(".*", StringComparison.OrdinalIgnoreCase))
        {
            return string.Equals(requestedNamespace, targetNamespace, StringComparison.OrdinalIgnoreCase);
        }
        requestedNamespace = requestedNamespace.Substring(0, requestedNamespace.Length - ".*".Length);
        if (!targetNamespace.StartsWith(requestedNamespace, StringComparison.OrdinalIgnoreCase))
        {
            return false;
        }
        return (requestedNamespace.Length == targetNamespace.Length) || (targetNamespace[requestedNamespace.Length] == '.');
    }
}
```

Finally, at `Application_Start`, make the following call.

```
ControllerBuilder.Current.SetControllerFactory(new ControllerFactory());
```

Comment: It's missing `Loaded.cs` and how `FromConfig` is populated.